# Custom Jtable Header has different layout then the other headers

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, jtableheader

I have a table with 3 columns, the first column is special and contains a checkbox instead of a title.

The problem is that the layout (appareance) of the checkbox header is different from the other headers. Can anyone help?

The Code:

```
import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  
import javax.swing.table.*;  
import java.awt.event.*; 

public class JTableHeaderCheckBox  
{  
  Object colNames[] = {"", "String", "String"};  
  Object[][] data = {};  
  DefaultTableModel dtm;  
  JTable table;  
  public void buildGUI()  
  {  
    dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data,colNames);  
    table = new JTable(dtm);  
    for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++)  
    {  
      dtm.addRow(new Object[]{new Boolean(false),"Row "+(x+1)+" Col 2","Row "+(x+1)+" Col 3"});  
    }  
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);  
    TableColumn tc = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);  
    tc.setCellEditor(table.getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class));  
    tc.setCellRenderer(table.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class));  
    tc.setHeaderRenderer(new CheckBoxHeader());  
    JFrame f = new JFrame();  
    f.getContentPane().add(sp);  
    f.pack();  
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    f.setVisible(true);  
  }  

  public static void main (String[] args)  
  {  
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){  
      public void run(){  
        new JTableHeaderCheckBox().buildGUI();  
      }  
    });  
  }  
}  

class CheckBoxHeader extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer {  
    protected CheckBoxHeader rendererComponent;  
    protected int column;  

    public CheckBoxHeader() {  
        rendererComponent = this;   
    }  

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {  
        setColumn(column);   
        return rendererComponent;  
    }  

    protected void setColumn(int column) {  
        this.column = column;  
    }  
    public int getColumn() {  
        return column;  
    }    
}
```

The wierd output:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
What I want:

1. Center align the checkbox in the header
2. If you pay close attention, you notice the background of the checkbox Header (**it seems popping to the inside**) is different from the other 2 headers (**they seem popping out**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're referring to the border of the checkbox you can try this to make the header look more consistent:

```
public CheckBoxHeader() {  
    rendererComponent = this;  

    setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    setBorderPaintedFlat(true);
    setBorderPainted(true);
}
```

Comment: Ok, the border is fine now. How do I **center-align** the checkbox in the table header? If you answer this one, I will accept your answer.

Comment: I have modified your answer to add the solution for the center-alignment. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3):

`TableCellRenderer` returns `JLabel/JComponents` and these [JComponents haven't got implemented any LayoutManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575641/how-returns-xxxsize-from-jcomponents-added-to-the-jlabel), but there isn't any restictions for setting some of `LayoutManagers`

Comment: so how can I replicate the effect of the other table headers (String, String)?

Comment: If you are saying I should set a layout, may I ask how can I get the Layout used for the other 2 headers?

Comment: hehehe good question, that's only about that you put a JComponent to the TableHeader/Cell

Comment: TableHeader have got same logics as TableCell there is only about ColumnModel :-)

Comment: Sorry man but I am very confused and lost (Work Overload)!! Could you please provide me with a fix in the shape of code?

Comment: what do you want 1) center JCheckBox to CENTER ??? 2) align another TableColumn same way as is placed JCheckBox in the 1st column ???

Comment: I answering by posting here simle shortcuts, very interesting question by @trashgod http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137786/how-can-i-put-a-control-in-the-jtableheader-of-a-jtable, there are described more than layout issue

Comment: Max's answer was what I wanted, you have to set the horizontalAlignment, BorderPaintedFlat and BorderPainted. Anyway, thanks for your time and answer