# Can I have a textfield inside a label?

Tags: java, swing, textfield, jlabel, jtextfield

What I would like to do is display the following in a form:

```
Open [15] minutes before class
```

Where `[15]` is a **text-field.**  Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a 'composite component' by adding the required parts to a `JPanel`.  E.G.

[image: TimeBeforeClass]

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

class TimeBeforeClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 3,3));
                gui.add(new JLabel("Open"));
                gui.add(new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(15,0,20,1)));
                gui.add(new JLabel("minutes before class"));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note that I swapped the 'textfield' for a `JSpinner` - a more suitable component for selecting 'time in minutes'.

Answer (score 3):

```
Can I have a textfield inside a label?
```

- answer is, yes you can, this is basic property of Java `AWT / Swing` Objects
- `JComboBox`, `JTable`, `JList`, `JSpinner`, `JFile(Color)Chooser`.... are compound `JComponents`, you can extract all `JComponent` and put that together again.
- you can put any of `JComponents` to the another
- only `JFrame/JDialog/JWindow` and `JPanel` have got implemented `LayoutManager` by default in the API, [for rest of then you have to implements proper LayoutManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575641/how-returns-xxxsize-from-jcomponents-added-to-the-jlabel)

Answer (score 1):

I think I have not understood. But, I'll try:

You can  get the text from a TextField:

label.setText("Open " + textField.getText()+ " minutes before class");

Comment: This can be a good alternative, just that OP failed to ellaborate a bit further on the situation in hand. +1 for this :-)