# Allow only integers and decimal values in JFormattedTextField or JTextField in Swing

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

How to allow only integers and decimal values in `JFormattedTextField` or `JTextField` in Java Swing. I'm using Intellij idea GUI form designer - grid layout manager.

As it automatically creates the variable in class am not able to set mask formatter or `NumberFormat`. How to do to allow only int and float numbers?

Comment: Use a `JSpinner` as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10021773/418556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Formatted TextFields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for working examples.