# Limit number of decimal places of JFormattedTextField (Both UI appearance and data structure)

Tags: java, swing

```
private JFormattedTextField getCurrencyJFormattedTextField() {
    NumberFormat format= NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);    
    NumberFormatter formatter= new NumberFormatter(format);
    formatter.setMinimum(0.0);
    formatter.setValueClass(Double.class);
    JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
    return formattedTextField;
}
```

So, if I explicitly key in "1.23456789"

UI of JFormattedTextField will show "1.2346"

However, when call `getValue`, the returned value is `1.23456789`, not `1.23461`

```
final double price = (Double)jFormattedTextField.getValue();
```

Is there any way to WYSIWYG? So that the underlying data structure will be consistence with UI display?

Comment: Most of the settings you have supplied are about formatting the underlying value, not restricting it's data entry.  About the only thing I can think of is using a `DocumentFilter` to restrict what the user can actually enter...

Comment: You might have better luck using a `JSpinner` as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10021773/418556). Though note that floating point numbers are generally of no exact value, as you seem to want.

Answer (score 1):

**You have to use `BigDecimal` as your data type.** It is specifically created for arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers.