# joptionpane default value showinputdialog

Tags: java, swing, default-value, joptionpane

Can i do that ? I want to set default value of my option pane is 9090..
This is my option pane code

```
private static int setPortNumber()
{
    String portNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
            "Enter the Port number for server creation","Server Connection\n",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    int PORT = Integer.parseInt(portNumber);

    return PORT;

}
```

Comment: The user would probably prefer seeing a `JSpinner` (with a `SpinnerNumberModel`) for the component.  You'd pass it as the object to the option pane `showMessageDialog(..)`, and query it straight afterwards in the next line of code..  E.G. as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10021773/418556).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

```
private static int setPortNumber()
{

    String [] possiblePorts = { "9090", "8080", "8081" }; 
    String selectedPort = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Select the Port number for server creation", "Server Connection\n", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, null, possiblePorts, possiblePorts[0]);

    int PORT = Integer.parseInt(selectedPort);

    return PORT;

}
```

In this way user need not to write just select.

Comment: wow other good answer.. but there is a little error, you must add `(String)` before JOptionPane.

Answer (score 3):

```
String portNumber = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
        "Enter the Port number for server creation",
        "Server Connection\n", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, null,
        null, "9090");
```

Read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)