# How to get text from a Document Filter Text Field

Tags: java, swing, textfield, documentfilter

I followed this example to only allow number input [How to allow introducing only digits in jTextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477354/how-to-allow-introducing-only-digits-in-jtextfield)

but now it wont let me use `textField.getText();`
do I have to call a different method to get the text after using the document filter?

also does it need to be just a `JTextField`? is a formatted text field bad?

EDIT:

```
package inputinteger;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException; 
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter.FilterBypass;

public class InputInteger
{
private JTextField tField;
private JLabel label=new JLabel();
private MyDocumentFilter documentFilter;

private void displayGUI()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Input Integer Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(
        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    tField = new JTextField(10);
    ((AbstractDocument)tField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(
            new MyDocumentFilter());
    tField.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            tFieldKeyPressed(evt);
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(tField); 
    contentPane.add(label);


    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
private void tFieldKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    label.setText(tField.getText());
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            new InputInteger().displayGUI();
        }
    };
    EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
}
}

class MyDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter{
    @Override
public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int off
                    , String str, AttributeSet attr) 
                            throws BadLocationException 
{
    // remove non-digits
    fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr);
} 
@Override
public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int off
        , int len, String str, AttributeSet attr) 
                        throws BadLocationException 
{
    // remove non-digits
    fb.replace(off, len, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr);
}
}
```

So this code works fine, but in the program im building, what im doing is using the NetBeans GUI builder and have a `JFormattedTextField` that I want to only accept Numbers as input. I tried adding Post creation code and it seems to have worked but now it throws an error that it cant find the `JFormattedTextField` (in my case creditInput)

It may just be something very simple that I am too tired to see right now. I will dig in deeper in the morning. If anyone can see my problem though id appreciate any input!

EDIT 2:
This is the code I have in NetBeans

```
    javax.swing.JFormattedTextField creditsInput = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
    ((AbstractDocument)creditsInput.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new MyDocumentFilter());
```

Later on in the code...

```
creditsInput.getText();//THIS LINE SAYS Symbol creditsInput cannot be found in class \
```

also I cant enter letters into the text box, so that part works i just need to be able to get the value of whats entered now.

Comment: Nope, simply call getText. It will return a a String, but the filter will prevent any characters you don't want from reaching the underlying Document and therefore the text field. What errors are you getting? Can you post a runnable example that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Updated my question with an example of basically what im doing. The problem is it works in my example... More details in the edit section of my question

Comment: _"now it throws an error that it cant find the JFormattedTextField (in my case creditInput)"_ - Where exaxtly _is_ `creditInput` input in the code? I don't see it.

Comment: ugh. I'm sorry I was tired as I was writing this. I will edit question to be more applicable to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I dont know what I was doing wrong, but deleting the Formatted Text Field and using a regular TextField seems to work just fine.

Comment: Consider using a `JSpinner` as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10021773/418556).

Comment: I said I got it to work. Although JSpinner could be another possibility.

Comment: Yes, I read that..  It is just that `JSpinner` is an *altogether* better alternative as far as the user is concerned.  For example, could I, as the user use the up/down arrow keys to select a number?  If not, that would hack me off.  A spinner allows that, provides automatic bounding for the values..

Comment: I see that makes sense. Thank you for the suggestion. (I just think they look ugly =/ )

Comment: Try the spinner in the native PLAF.