# How to change my grid size (using JTextField)

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

So I have bunch of grids on my window and I have a `JTextField`, I want to write a number, say

20, in the text field and the 20 would change my grid size to 20 and so on.

Here you see I have set it to 30, I can set it to any number, but like I said I want to be

able to change/set the number when I type it in the text field after I run the program.

This is my Grids class and not the main class, In my main class I created the text field and

such. Also I have my `actionPreformed` in my main so what do I need in my `actionPreformed`

(if necessary)?

So my question is after running the program how to write in the text field a

number (10,20,30 any number) and be able to change my grid size based on the number I typed?

Also what do I need in my `actionPreformed` (if necessary)?

Grids class:

```
protected int gridSize = 30; // how many grids
public Grids( ghetto ttt  )
{
   setLayout( new GridLayout( gridSize, gridSize ) );
   theSquares = new Marker[gridSize][gridSize];
   for ( int i=0; i<gridSize; i++ )
   {
       for ( int j=0; j<gridSize; j++ )
       {
           theSquares[i][j] = new Marker(gridSize , this );
           add(theSquares[i][j]);
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: Use a `JSpinner` for this. E.G. as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10021773/418556).

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `JSpinner` with a `ChangeListener`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 1):

So an actionlistener probably won't work. That condenses click events into ActionEvents. What you can do is add a document listener. See [Value Change Listener to JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield).

In your main program where you would do

```
    textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // Whatever
        }
    });
```

you do

```
 textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
            //whatever
        }
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
            //whatever
        }
        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
            //whatever
        }
    });
```

Comment: And where could this go in my main class under actionPreformed?

Comment: not under actionPerformed. This would have to be attached to your jtextfield in the same way that an actionListener would.

Comment: Um, not sure if I understood, do you mind writing this part in a code?

Comment: @user3412136 Added an example