# JTextField Specific format checking

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, bigdecimal

I want to check if the input  entered to  my `JTextField1` equal to shown sample picture below, how to do that?

I can only check if numbers entered by putting below code in to try block and catch `NumberFormatException`

```
   try {
       taxratio = new BigDecimal(jTextField1.getText());  }
      } 
         catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("Error" + nfe.getMessage());
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you use JFormattedTextField instead?

Comment: let me try , in swing pallet netbeans IDE there is but how to check it let me see

Comment: ok but how to check if it is correct format

Comment: Use a `JSpinner` as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10021773/418556).

Comment: Use JFormattedTextField. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html

Comment: but sometimes user inputs like this  0.18 instead %18 so my calculation becomes wrong because my formula calculate wrong if the input is 0.18

Comment: Using JFormattedTextField corrects the input only if the input is 0.18 it does 1800 ,  it is actually %18 , if the input %18 I divide by hundred to obtain 0.18 ,but user input can differ thats why I am having issue !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options:

**A `JTextField` with an `InputVerifier`**. The text field will not yield focus unless its contents are of the form specified.

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textField.setInputVerifier(new InputVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
        String text = ((JTextField) input).getText();
        if (text.matches("%\\d\\d"))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
});
textField.setText("%  ");
```

---

**A `JFormattedTextField` with a `MaskFormatter`**. The text field will not accept typed characters which do not comply with the mask specified. You ca set the placeholder character to a digit if you want a default number to appear when there is no input.

```
MaskFormatter mask = new MaskFormatter("%##");
mask.setPlaceholderCharacter(' '); 
JFormattedTextField textField2 = new JFormattedTextField(mask);
```