# NumberFormatException on JTextField value

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, numberformatexception

Trying to insert an entry into a database by a radio button Option throws me this Exception
I tried to get answer by the similar questions but i did not get one.

The code is as follows :

```
private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   jPanel2.setVisible(true);
    try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
      Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","Sumit");
      String query="Insert student values(?,?,?)";
      PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
      pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
      pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
      pst.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText()));
      int rec=pst.executeUpdate();
      if(rec>0)
      {
          jLabel6.setText("New Student Added");
          jTextField1.setText(" ");
         jTextField2.setText(" ");
          jTextField3.setText(" ");
      }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  After examining stack trace I found The error is on line no 194 where I parse an Integer from `jTextField3`.

Comment: What is the content of the `jTextField3` maybe this is not an Integer?

Comment: jTextfield3 in my table requires int, a roll number.

Comment: Yes it requires one. But if you insert a non numeric value you get exect these exception.

Comment: `jTextField3` should be `jSpinner`..

Comment: E.G. Use a `JSpinner` as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10021773/418556).

Answer (score 2):

`jTextField3` does not contain any text that can be parsed into a number, either it contains a string that consists of non-digits or it is empty. Therefore `pst.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText()));` throws a NumberFormatException when trying to convert the text in the textfield into an integer. For full description of parseInt you can check the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).

The NumberFormatException contains a message which tells you what the input string looked like, for instance `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "xyz"`

Comment: Also, the NumberformatException should provide information on what is wrong, e.g.: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " "

Comment: Pphoenix I want to enter the values through the text Field.How can i set jtextfield before? the input string is ""

Comment: @SumitDhiman Easiest way (skipping StringBuilder) int defaultValue = 5; jTextField3.setText(""+defaultValue); // Now textfield contains the number 5