# Two images in JTreeNode?

Tags: java, image, swing, jtree, renderer

I have some custom JTree. That tree has nodes with custom icons. I also have a class that extends `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` with method `getTreeCellRendererComponent` as simple as this:

```
super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
MyTreeNode node = ((MyTreeNode) value);
Icon icon = node.getIcon();
setIcon(icon);
return this;
```

It works. My tree nodes will be rendered with custom icons in `ICON TEXT` format. BUT! Is there a way to put TWO icons in my node! I would like to have a node that looks like this: `ICON TEXT ANOTHER_JLABEL_WITH_IMAGE`.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your own `TreeCellRenderer` that extends from something like a `JPanel`.

This way, you can define your own layout requirements and add your own components to support your requirements

Answer (score 2):

You can also create an Icon which combines two (or more) other icons. See for example http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/

Answer (score 1):

The default component used to render a Tree node is a JLabel. Thus you have access to the `setIcon` method.

But if you want to set two icons to a node you need to create a JPanel with two labels in it.

Comment: I tried that, but then my tree (with 11 000 nodes) is too slow!

Comment: You must not create a two icons label per node, but only one for the entire tree. You should have a look on how TreeCellRenderer is designed (flyweight pattern).

Comment: You mean, like i "singleton label" that is used in all nodes?

Comment: `with 11 000 nodes ???` == apply `Renderer` only to the visible `Rectangle` returned from `JVievport`

Comment: This is already handled by Swing. Only the nodes being shown are painted.

Answer (score 1):

- `(J)Component` / `JLabel` (returned by `Renderer`) haven't implemented any `LayoutManager` in the API
- right `JLabel` has constructor for `Text` and `Icon`, there is not place for another `Icon`
- basically every `JComponents` are containers too, part of `Containers` have got implemented `LayoutManager` in the API (`JFrame`, `JPanel`), you can to put any `JComponent` to the another
- [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8575641/714968)
- [great workarounds](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/?s=icon) by camickr, especially `Compound Icon`