# Displaying a JLabel on top of another JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have the following code:

```
try {
        File file_background = new File(
                "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\background.png");
        ImageIcon icon_background = new ImageIcon(
                ImageIO.read(file_background));
        JLabel background = new JLabel(icon_background);
        window.setContentPane(background);

        File file_car = new File(
                "C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Desktop\\car.png");
        ImageIcon icon_car = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(file_car));

        JLabel car = new JLabel(icon_car);
        car.setVisible(true);

        background.add(car);
        // TODO Get car showing on top of the background label

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Where I'm attempting to have the car label show on TOP of the background label. But I'm only getting the background JLabel showing. I'm new to SWING so any suggestions to what steps I'm missing would be great.

Comment: have you tried making the label on top non-opaque?

Comment: depends of, question do you want to moving with `JLabel car` ???, or this figure is static

Comment: @mre glad to see you here again

Comment: Yeah I want to move it a later stage. But right now I want it to show first :)

Comment: @mre - Tried that. Didn't do anything

Comment: @mKorbel, Thanks, it's nice to see you again too! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ..I want to move it a later stage. But right now I want it to show first :)

There are two ways,

#### 1st.

- Put `JLabel car`  to `JPanel`, drawing an `Image` by using `paintComponent`, instead of `JLabel background` (advantage `JPanel` is container with proper notifications for `LayoutManager`).
- Put `JLabel car`  to `JLabel background`, but `JLabel` haven't implemented any `LayoutManager`, have to set desired.

  1. Advantage all images in `JLabel` are static, with zero CPU and GPU inpact ad consumption in compare with `paintComponent`.
  2. Disadvantage `JLabel` isn't container and with proper notifications for `LayoutManager`, required a few code lones moreover in compare with `JLabel` placed in  `JPanel`, for movement (AbsoluteLayout) is quite good solution.

#### 2nd.

Draw both `Images` by using [BufferedImage and Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7940227/714968).

Answer (score 3):

Add them both to a JPanel that uses [OverlayLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html). It is not ok to add a `JLabel` to another `JLabel`.

This code has not gone through a compiler so take it for what it is :)

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new OverlayLayout());
panel.add(background);
panel.add(car);
```

Comment: Can you please explain why it's not okay to add a JLabel to another JLabel? Thanks

Comment: Look at the documentation for JPanel. It is designed to contain other JComponents (and JLabel is a JComponent). JLabel indirectly inherits from Container which is an AWT component designed to contain other AWT components. It is confusing, but I would guess that you will run into several issues similar to what you just did (layout not working) if you don't use a JPanel.

Comment: Oh okay. So you want me to change them both from JLabel to JPanel and then use the OverlayLayout in order to display one over the other?

Comment: +1 for layout JLabel by OverLayLayout, but this is one good reason to lay JLabel in JLabel,

Comment: @mKorbel, if it is a good idea to put a JComponent in another JComponent, then why is there a JPanel?

Comment: correct question, you are right, but depends of, for this issue and layed by OverLayLayout doesn't matter, because is about null layout, but for rest of standard layout managers [could be non_sence do that or not ???](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575641/how-returns-xxxsize-from-jcomponents-added-to-the-jlabel) still opened question

Comment: there are a few question last year (about icon into icon in JLabel), where is used JLabel as contianer ....

Comment: Thanks, really interesting :)

Comment: There's an `OverlayLayout` example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13437388/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Works.. Added the following to make it display:

```
car.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200);
```

Apparently it's because by default a null layout manager is used. So setting the bounds of the label will enable it to display since the default size is 0.

Comment: the default layout manager is never the null layout manager...you must be setting this explicitly somewhere, which I highly recommend you change.