# How to put JButton on JLabel?

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I'm making app in Java Swing with Netbeans IDE. In my app I put multiple `JInternalFrame` on `JDesktopPane`. I put JLabel on JinternalFrame. I set Image in JLabel like

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/myImage.jpg")));
```

now i want to add JButton on that Label.So,

How to put `JButton` on `JLabel` (which contain `Image`) in Java Swing?

Sorry for late update. What i want to do is in below picture.
[image]
Before Image.

After Image.(What i want it here.)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to add an icon to a button?  Your question is very confusing.

Comment: what do you want exactly? a label to behave as a button?

Comment: use FlowLayout for JLabel with right alingment, then everything is placed from right top corner to left :-),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for reply to me and helping to me. I had done and solve my problem with the help of GridBagLayOut and GridBagConstraints as per my below code :

```
enter code here

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author JAY
 */
public class HomePageOfApp {

    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JButton aboutUsBtn;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JButton powerBtn;
    private javax.swing.JButton presetBtn;
    private javax.swing.JButton settingBtn;
    static JInternalFrame internalFrame = null;
    private static final GridBagConstraints gbc;

    static {
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    }

    public HomePageOfApp() {
        initComponents();
        internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Home Page", false, false, true, false);
        internalFrame.setBounds(0, 0, 784, 434);
        internalFrame.setLocation(0, 0);
        internalFrame.setContentPane(wrapInBackgroundImage(jPanel1,
                new ImageIcon(
                getClass().getResource("/myImage1.jpg"))));
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        powerBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        presetBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        aboutUsBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        settingBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();


        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        powerBtn.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("E:\\Image2_60.png")); // NOI18N
        powerBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
        powerBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        powerBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
        powerBtn.setPressedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("E:\\Image2_50.png")); // NOI18N
        powerBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                powerBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = -31;
        gridBagConstraints.ipady = -8;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(106, 27, 0, 0);
        jPanel1.add(powerBtn, gridBagConstraints);

        presetBtn.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("E:\\Image2_60.png")); // NOI18N
        presetBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
        presetBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        presetBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
        presetBtn.setPressedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("E:\\Image2_50.png")); // NOI18N
        presetBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                presetBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 3;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = -31;
        gridBagConstraints.ipady = -8;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(106, 26, 0, 19);
        jPanel1.add(presetBtn, gridBagConstraints);

        aboutUsBtn.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("E:\\Image2_60.png")); // NOI18N
        aboutUsBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
        aboutUsBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        aboutUsBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
        aboutUsBtn.setPressedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("E:\\Image2_50.png")); // NOI18N
        aboutUsBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                aboutUsBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = -31;
        gridBagConstraints.ipady = -8;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(42, 57, 32, 0);
        jPanel1.add(aboutUsBtn, gridBagConstraints);

        settingBtn.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("E:\\Image2_60.png")); // NOI18N
        settingBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
        settingBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        settingBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
        settingBtn.setPressedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("E:\\Image2_50.png")); // NOI18N
        settingBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                settingBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = -31;
        gridBagConstraints.ipady = -8;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(42, 27, 32, 0);
        jPanel1.add(settingBtn, gridBagConstraints);

    }

    private void powerBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void presetBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void aboutUsBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void settingBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    /**
     * Wraps a Swing JComponent in a background image. Simply invokes the overloded
     * variant with Top/Leading alignment for background image.
     *
     * @param component - to wrap in the a background image
     * @param backgroundIcon - the background image (Icon)
     * @return the wrapping JPanel
     */
    public static JPanel wrapInBackgroundImage(JComponent component,
            Icon backgroundIcon) {
        return wrapInBackgroundImage(
                component,
                backgroundIcon,
                JLabel.TOP,
                JLabel.CENTER);
    }

    /**
     * Wraps a Swing JComponent in a background image. The vertical and horizontal
     * alignment of background image can be specified using the alignment
     * contants from JLabel.
     *
     * @param component - to wrap in the a background image
     * @param backgroundIcon - the background image (Icon)
     * @param verticalAlignment - vertical alignment. See contants in JLabel.
     * @param horizontalAlignment - horizontal alignment. See contants in JLabel.
     * @return the wrapping JPanel
     */
    public static JPanel wrapInBackgroundImage(JComponent component,
            Icon backgroundIcon,
            int verticalAlignment,
            int horizontalAlignment) {

        // make the passed in swing component transparent
        component.setOpaque(false);

        // create wrapper JPanel
        JPanel backgroundPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        backgroundPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        // add the passed in swing component first to ensure that it is in front
        backgroundPanel.add(component, gbc);

        // create a label to paint the background image
        JLabel backgroundImage = new JLabel(backgroundIcon);

        // set minimum and preferred sizes so that the size of the image
        // does not affect the layout size
        backgroundImage.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1, 1));
        backgroundImage.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1, 1));

        // align the image as specified.
        backgroundImage.setVerticalAlignment(verticalAlignment);
        backgroundImage.setHorizontalAlignment(horizontalAlignment);

        // add the background label
        backgroundPanel.add(backgroundImage, gbc);

        // return the wrapper
        return backgroundPanel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that accesses posted images via `URL`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513).

Answer (score 2):

While it sounds like you could simply manipulate your image into an `ImageIcon` object and bind that to the `JButton`, you could change the `Z index` of your two components. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29) is the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

> How to put JButton on JLabel (which contain Image) in Java Swing?

- JLabel and rest of JComponents haven't implemented any LayoutManager, required to set LayoutManager
- every Swing JComponents (most of AWT Components too) can be contianers too
- excluding JFrame/ContentPane - BorderLayout and JPanel - FlowLayout
- [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575641/how-returns-xxxsize-from-jcomponents-added-to-the-jlabel)

Comment: While this is all true, non of it will take in consideration the existing icon or text of the label...

Comment: @MadProgrammer only to override getPreferredSize() for JLabel (for LayoutManager, JFrame/JPanel has this method in API), then is possible another jungle with JLabel, JButton (lots of Icon in each of corners) or relayout compound JComponents (remove ArrowButton from JSpinner) ....

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OverlayLayout`, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13437388/230513).

[image]

Addendum: Also consider @Andrew Thompson's approach, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513), in which a portion taken from an overlying image is used as a button's *pressed* icon.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping to me. Your approach is good. But i solved my problem as per i said in below.