# JOptionPane icon gets cropped in Windows 10

Tags: java, swing, windows-10, look-and-feel

I am using the following code to present an error dialog in Java Swing:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Arquivo de imagem não encontrado. Por gentileza, altere o caminho do arquivo.", "Erro",  JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

using Windows 10 default look and feel through:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

But the icon looks cropped, like this:

[image: Dialog with cropped icon]

Any ideas on how to solve that?

Here is the SSCCE:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class SSCCE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error message", "Error",  JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem so other people using Windows 10 can verify if it is a problem.

Comment: All GUI creation & update should be on the EDT.

Comment: This seems like the same issue here: [Bad Swing UI scaling on high resolution (MS Surface)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774828/bad-swing-ui-scaling-on-high-resolution-ms-surface)

Comment: Sure, it seems to be the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like Oracle has finally taken notice of this and [will fix it in JDK 9](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8151385), but for the time being here's a qiuck, hacky and Windows dependent solution for those not willing to provide custom icons.

Insert this code after your call to `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()`:

```
try
{
    String[][] icons =
    {
        {"OptionPane.errorIcon", "65581"},
        {"OptionPane.warningIcon", "65577"},
        {"OptionPane.questionIcon", "65579"},
        {"OptionPane.informationIcon", "65583"}
    };
    //obtain a method for creating proper icons
    Method getIconBits = Class.forName("sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2").getDeclaredMethod("getIconBits", new Class[]{long.class, int.class});
    getIconBits.setAccessible(true);
    //calculate scaling factor
    double dpiScalingFactor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution() / 96.0;
    int icon32Size = (dpiScalingFactor == 1)?(32):((dpiScalingFactor == 1.25)?(40):((dpiScalingFactor == 1.5)?(45):((int) (32 * dpiScalingFactor))));
    Object[] arguments = {null, icon32Size};
    for (String[] s:icons)
    {
        if (UIManager.get(s[0]) instanceof ImageIcon)
        {
            arguments[0] = Long.valueOf(s[1]);
            //this method is static, so the first argument can be null
            int[] iconBits = (int[]) getIconBits.invoke(null, arguments);
            if (iconBits != null)
            {
                //create an image from the obtained array
                BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(icon32Size, icon32Size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                img.setRGB(0, 0, icon32Size, icon32Size, iconBits, 0, icon32Size);
                ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
                //override previous icon with the new one
                UIManager.put(s[0], newIcon);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

### Why this works

On Windows, icons provided to applications are already scaled by the current DPI setting (96 = no scaling, 120 = +25%, 144 = +50%).
Unfortunatelly, Java always assumes that icons are of size either 16x16 or 32x32, which is not the case.
The code above utilizes a native method `sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getIconBits()` used by Java to obtain OS icons, but provides appropriate sizes.
This approach may become unusable in the future, as `Win32ShellFolder2` is not part of the API and may be modified or removed entirely, but so far this is the only approach preserving the native icons.

Comment: I tried on my installation and the icon is much smaller and not correct. It was a JOptionPane with a Warning icon

Answer (score 3):

mkJ720's answer works well, but the icon ID's are off. Here are the corrected ones:

```
String[][] icons = {
    {"OptionPane.warningIcon",     "65581"},
    {"OptionPane.questionIcon",    "65583"},
    {"OptionPane.errorIcon",       "65585"},
    {"OptionPane.informationIcon", "65587"}
};
```

Comment: In case someone is still looking for a solution to this problem, this set of icon IDs seems to be correct on my machine, but icon is different on tester's machine for exactly the same message. Mine is a  mini-desktop, hers is a laptop, both windows10, the system update is in full-control by IT department.

Comment: Wonder how do you get the number, e.g. "65581", "65583", etc., for each icon. Tried on a couple more laptops; on some laptops, the Error message has a red X icon, and the Confirmation message has a blue ? icon; on the other laptops, the Error message has the blue ? icon, and the Confirmation message has a yellow ! icon. DIFFERENT result on DIFFERENT machine!