# Why is my JFreeChart rendering improperly?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I am trying to build a simple JFreeChart XYLineChart object, and embed it into a ChartPanel object.

For some unknown reason, the plot area doesn't look properly: You can see how gridlines are inconsistent in thickness, and the edges of the plot have these thick black markings in random places. What could be the cause of this?

```
public class Main extends JFrame() {

public static void main (String [] args) {
ECGPanel myECGPanel = new ECGPanel();
this.add(myECGPanel);
      }

}


public class ECGPanel extends Jpanel {
lineChart= ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("ECG", "Time(ms)", "Voltage(mV)", dataset,
                      PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, false, false);

 chartPanel=new ChartPanel(lineChart);
 chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,400));

 this.add(chartPanel);
}
```

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: Windows with a display scale factor of 150% (or something else but 100%)?

Comment: @user16320675 sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Are you using a WIndows System? If yes, is the display scale of your system set to some value other than 100%? (e.g. the *default* 150% - right click on the desktop - `Display settings`)

Comment: @user16320675 It seems to be solved when I switch the scale from 125% to 100%. But I can't keep the computer on those settings. Do you know why this doesn't happen when I embed my JFreeChart in a SwingNode inside a JavaFX project? It happens only with pure Swing

Comment: This seems more like a layout problem. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that reproduces the result shown.

Comment: Swing does not interpolate images properly on Windows systems with screen scaling.  You can eliminate the scaling by running your Java application with [one of these commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555401/java-disable-dpi-aware-not-working/57926454#57926454).

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out in comments, the problem relates to Windows and its Display settings. I have found the discussion about how Swing behaves on higher DPI systems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37254865/5356111)

Interestingly, I don't have this problem when I create a JFreeChart in JavaFX (both using a SwingNode and when using a ChartViewer). You can also see read about that [here](http://kynosarges.org/GuiDpiScaling.html)

Comment: Such artifacts are usually the result of a double-buffering using the logical component size as the buffer’s pixel size. So, I’d try `false` for the `useBuffer` parameter of [this constructor](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#ChartPanel-org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart-boolean-).

Comment: This may be a layout problem. The default layout of `JPanel`, `FlowLayout`, ignores preferred size, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513); what is `Jpanel`?

Comment: @Holger that fixed it! You can post an answer so I accept it